# jVectorMap add more markers after map is created

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I have a full us jvectormap.  I want to show markers when you zoom into a state, great I have that completed...

I use this

```
var mapObject = $('#vmap').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

to get my map into an object and then use the following to put markers on the map...

```
mapObject.addMarkers(eval(dealers), []);
```

My array is set up as... (example)...

```
//mapObject.addMarkers([{ latLng: [42.940893, -71.444068], name: 'Test' }], []);
```

Now my question is say I want to still use the AddMarkers function but I want to add markers with different colors that represent different things would I have to switch to dataseries instead of just an array above?  I am not clear on teh documentation when using the map as an object to add data, I understand how it works when you create a map object but not like how I am using it above...any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that I had to add an addition object to my array.

I did an if function to base on color I wanted to use...then did the following...

style = {
r: 3,
fill: 'black'
};

Then added it into the original dealers object.